# Plupload IE Upload - Illegal Char Issue

Tags: asp.net, plupload

I implemented plupload ajax uploader for uploading videos and audio files in asp.net application. its working fine on all other browsers except IE (testing on 9.0) using Flash as runtime.

Here is screen shot i received on IE when flash as runtime used.

[image]

Here is sample code i am using.

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes: 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
        browse_button: 'MC_uploader_v31_pickfiles',
        container: 'container',
        max_file_size: '1000mb',
        url: 'http://localhost/vuploader/videos/upload/upload.ashx',
        flash_swf_url: 'http://localhost/vuploader/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',
        silverlight_xap_url: 'http://localhost/vuploader/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap',
        //chunk_size: '4mb',
        //unique_names: true,
        filters: [
        { title: 'Media Files', extensions: 'mp4,wmv,mpeg,mpg,flv,avi,rm,mov,m4v,dv,ogg,ogv,webm'}],
        headers: { UName: '', MTP: '0' }
    });
```

Here is upload handler code sample.

```
 int chunk = context.Request["chunk"] != null ? int.Parse(context.Request["chunk"]) : 0;
 string fileName = context.Request["name"] != null ? context.Request["name"] : string.Empty;
 HttpPostedFile fileUpload = context.Request.Files[0];
 using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName), chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
 {
     var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
     fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
 }
```

Code working fine on all browsers except IE. Can any one help what will be the reason of this issue.

Comment: Are you able to set a break point when debugging on the using line and inspect what values are held by uploadPath, fileName when in IE ?

Comment: i tried, not tracking the cause. other browsers uses html5 as runtime and its working fine. i think there is problem in flash runtime.

Comment: Are you receiving the error code when uploading your file ? If so, are you using session state ? The flash client won't have access to your session cookie, wich is probably HttpOnly, and your upload attempt will end-up triggering session_start, and fail. 
You should first try disabling session state in your handler and see if it makes a difference (or put a breakpoint in your session_start to see if it is triggered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i found this was caused in flash player 11 which freezes existing .swf file provided by pluploader.

When upgrading to latest patch .swf file found on plupload forum.

http://www.diverse-tech.net/plupload_ex/plupload.flash.swf

It fixed uploading problem via flash runtime.